# How would I save 100 color values for 100 tiles

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am generating textures for a pygame project and I need a way to save the color values for each 100 pixels in each 100 tiles.

ive been trying to use 4 dimensional arrays but that is just a mess.

```py
color = (0,0,0)

for i in range(0, 100):

            z = z + 1
            color = (0, random.randrange(100, 200), 0)
            colors = np.array([color])
            np.append(colors, [color])
            ycol = ycord/10
            print(colors[1])
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (xcord + x, ycord + y, 10, 10))
            xcord = xcord + 10
            if z == 10:
                ycord = ycord + 10
                xcord = 0
                z = 0
```

Obviously whenever I redraw the game the tiles textures completely change, I need them to stay the same.

Comment: What about a numpy matrix 5 colums time 100 rows? rows look like: coord_x, coord_y, r, g, b

Comment: One alternative approach would be to ensure the random colours are the same by using calling [random.seed(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) before generating your texture.